# How can I gain screen share/ssh access to a G5 connected by ethernet to a Mac Mini on my wireless Airport Extreme Network from my MacBook Pro?

Tags: ssh, screen-sharing, network

Ok, so the scenario is this:

I have a G5 Quad (running Leopard) with no wireless card.
The G5 is connected by ethernet to a Mac-Mini (running Lion), which is picking up my AirPort Extreme network over WiFi. The Mac-Mini shares it's internet connection over ethernet to the G5 enabling it to connect to the internet perfectly. I can also screen share or ssh into the G5 from the Mac-Mini without any problems.

Now comes the trouble:

I have a MacBook Pro (running Lion) which also connects to the same WiFi network as the Mac-Mini. I can see (and connect to) the Mac-Mini from the MBP without trouble, but I cannot see or connect to the G5 from the MBP. How can I configure this so that I can ssh or screen share the G5 from my MBP?

IPs and subnets of machines:

Mac-Mini
IP: 10.0.0.9
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

MBP
IP: 10.0.0.4
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

G5
IP: 192.168.2.3 
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

Comment: Can you tell us the IP and subnet mask of the G5, the IP of the Mac Mini and of the Macbook Pro? They are in System Preferences, Network, (Select here your network interface), Advanced, TCP/IP

Comment: I've added the IPs and subnets for all of the machines. I have also discovered that I can screen share the G5 from my MBP by first screen sharing the Mini-Mac and then screen sharing again to the G5! It's a bit clunky but it works. What I would really like is direct ssh access.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the two machines are not on the same subnet.

The G5 is on the Mac Mini's subnet, while the Mac Mini is on your Wi-Fi's subnet. The IP address of the G5 has been handed out by the Internet Sharing DHCP service on your Mac Mini, while the Mac Mini's IP address has been handed out by the DHCP service on your router.

Your best bet would be to connect your G5 via Ethernet to your router.

If that is not possible because of location constraints, there is a piece of software for Mac called [IPNetRouterX](http://www.sustworks.com/site/prod_ipnrx_overview.html) that may do the job. It allows Ethernet bridging, which is what you want. The only problem with this software is that it costs money. It seems like there might be a free trial of it, however.

Comment: Would Mac OS X Lion Server be able to do the Job, running on the Mac Mini? It does cost less the IPNetRouterX.

Comment: Unfortunately not. To my knowledge, Mac OS X (any version) doesn't have the ability to act as an ethernet bridge. There may be other software out there that will do this, but I've heard good things about that one.

Answer (score 0):

iChat + [Chax](http://www.ksuther.com/chax/) (Relogin/Auto-accept Screen Share requiest) on G5 would be an easy way to achieve that, I believe.

Comment: Ideally I'm looking to rectify the networking issue so that I can gain ssh access. Screen sharing is only occasionally needed and I've found a way to fudge that already.

Comment: Well basically Mac Mini is a router for the G5 that is under NAT, so what you need is to configure port forwarding on the Mini like you would normally do with a router to gain access to specific machine under NAT. I hope this will be of any help.
P.S. Not exactly what you are looking for but could be a clue -- http://realprogrammers.com/hack/SSH/tunneling.html

Answer (score 0):

What if, in the G5 network preferences pane you click on Ethernet, then advanced, then tcp/ip, and as Configure IPv4 you select Manual, and as IPv4 address you use 10.0.0.5, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, and as Router 10.0.0.9? Then from the Macbook Pro you can say

`ssh user@10.0.0.5`

Does that work?

EDIT: Of course "Remote Login" has to be on the G5 as well.

Comment: No this doesn't work.